# Get exact variable from webpage using cURL

Tags: curl

with below code, we are able to get whole source code of web page,

```
<?php
$url1 = "http://adfoc.us/426491";
$ch = curl_init ("$url1");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://google.com/");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'));
$page = curl_exec ($ch);

echo '<textarea style="width:100%; height: 100%;">' . $page . '</textarea>';
?>
```

But my question is how to get specific variable from page, and echo it

eg:

```
var click_url = "http://somesite.com/serve/click/?id=426491&servehash=af183123696fe5064846368ca7191359&timestamp=1337499663";
```

i am new to cURL, so please explain it
Thanks :)